# Какую структуру нужно использовать для хранения данных, которые быстро добавляются и удаляются?

Tags: javascript, v8

Есть большое количество объектов (~10000+), в которые в произвольном порядке могут добавляться около 50 заранее известных новых свойств (с разными значениями). Когда свойство уже использовано и больше не нужно, оно удаляется через `delete`

* В частности, такое сложилось в игре: Система боевых эффектов персонажей, при размене ударов раз в пару секунд, у всех ботов регулярно включаются / выключаются разные эффекты.

Если искать в гугле что-то вроде «js engine optimization» можно найти статьи ( [пример-1](https://engineering.linecorp.com/en/blog/v8-hidden-class/#:%7E:text=A%20hidden%20class%20contains%20memory,offset%20of%20the%20new%20property.), [пример-2](https://blog.sessionstack.com/how-javascript-works-inside-the-v8-engine-5-tips-on-how-to-write-optimized-code-ac089e62b12e) ), где утверждается, что при создании объектов используется механизм "hidden class":

```
function Point(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
}

var p1 = new Point(1, 2);
p1.a = 5;
p1.b = 6;

var p2 = new Point(3, 4);
p2.b = 7;
p2.a = 8;
```

JS создает один скрытый класс для p1, и другой - для p2, т.к. свойства `a` и `b` добавляются в разном порядке. Соответственно, рекомендуется изначально добавлять все свойства в одинаковом порядке.

Отсюда вопросы:

1. Есть ли у этого механизма какие-то ограничения по максимальному количеству созданных классов? Очевидно, для 50 свойств физически невозможно создать `50!` классов. (или я не так понял, как это работает?)
2. Создавать объекты с одинаковыми, но пустыми свойствами, а вместо delete, давать им значения null / undefined — Хорошо или плохо? Изначально казалось, что используя delete, освобождаю память от лишних свойств. А на деле получается, это только забивает его - созданием новых скрытых классов, при добавлении новых свойств?

Comment: я ничего не понял...

Comment: На всякий случай, ещё пара статей от разработчиков V8: https://benediktmeurer.de/2018/06/14/javascript-engine-fundamentals-shapes-and-inline-caches/ и https://benediktmeurer.de/2018/08/16/javascript-engine-fundamentals-optimizing-prototypes/

Comment: Насколько я помню, один из авторов этих статей писал когда-то: создавайте естественный код для своих нужд, а оптимизацию предоставьте движку. Профилируйте, и, если упрётесь в недостаточную эффективность каких-то механизмов языка, напишите нам (например, в https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/list), чтобы мы попробовали оптимизировать ваш case на уровне движка.

Comment: Кстати, если будете обдумывать использование Map, вот как раз попалась небольшая статья о реализации этой структуры, там есть и об эффективности добавления и удаления элементов: https://itnext.io/v8-deep-dives-understanding-map-internals-45eb94a183df (перевод: https://habr.com/ru/company/ruvds/blog/518032/)

Answer (score 1):

1. "Когда свойство создается динамически, или свойство удаляется или изменяется, создается другой скрытый класс.". То есть каждый раз когда свойство создается динамически создается класс то есть сколько свойств только и классов (вообще создается класс не только при создании свойства но и изменении и удалении, но так будет проще) по этому лимитов практически нету (уж точно не меньше чем свойств).
2. Присваивать значения null / undefined и delete это одно и тоже.
   Вообще для небольших массивов / объектов delete подходит тем что можно будет использовать метод filter что бы вычистить его от всего лишнего, но в случае с большим массивом / объектом (~10000+) этот способ не подходит. И да это только больше забивает память вместо очищения.